Why does the internal resistance of LiMnO2 Li-ion cells increase over time even if not in use?
In my project, I used non-rechargeable Lithium-Manganese Dioxide (LiMnO2) batteries, as shown in the following figure. In the figure, the series-parallel battery cells are connected to a circuit through a p-channel MOSFET for battery monitoring purposes. When the Enable pin is activated, the supply of the Battery Management Board (BMB) circuit is connected, allowing it to work as a Coulomb counter.

I conducted a test on a batch of about 30 batteries with the Enable pin disabled. In the test, the no-load voltage of the batteries and their internal resistance were measured through the Positive and Negative terminals. The batteries were then set aside without any use for about a month. After this period, I measured the same parameters using the same methods and tools. I observed that the no-load voltage of the batteries had decreased by about 0.5% on average, and the internal resistance had increased by about 30%.
I'm not sure why the internal resistance of the battery increased. Is the battery depleted, or is there another reason for the increase in internal resistance?
P.S.: In the following, I explain the method used for measuring internal resistance. I'm not sure if the method used for measuring the resistance is completely accurate; however, I used the same method for both tests to compare the internal resistance. Therefore, the actual resistance value is not important to me, but the change is very important.
To measure the internal resistance, I logged the voltage and current of the Positive and Negative Terminals by connecting a resistor of about 16 ohms to the terminal for a few seconds. The ratio of the voltage drop to the resistor current gives me the internal resistance. The voltage and current of a test are shown in the following figure.
The internal resistance in this test is calculated as follows:
Rint = (15.23-13.42)/0.7862= 2.3 ohm


You observed two known effects in Li-ion cells:

Self-discharge
Calendar life

While these effects affect all Li-ion chemistries, they are worse in LMO cells and result in a relatively short lifespan.
The open-circuit voltage (OCV) decreased because Li-ion cells do experience a small internal current that slowly discharges them. Li-ion cells have a far lower self-discharge current than other cell technologies, but are still not perfect. The self-discharge current is unavoidable and increases at high SOC levels and at high temperatures.
The resistance increased due to the growth of the SEI layer on the surface of the graphite electrode (solid electrolyte interphase). The SEI layer is good as it prevents unwanted chemical reactions that would make the cell useless, but it also consumes active material (Lithium metal) and increases cell resistance. This effect is unavoidable and increases at high temperatures.
There is also a third effect that you did not witness, but did occur: capacity fade. Li-ion cells lose capacity at a steady rate, even if not in use.

How could I measure the capacity fade of LiMnO2 batteries due to self-discharge?

"capacity fade of LiMnO2 batteries due to self-discharge?". You can't because there is no such thing: self-discharge doesn't cause capacity fade. Self discharge causes loss of charge, which is easily reversed by recharging a cell. Capacity fade is caused by growth of the SEI layer (as I already said in my answer), not by self-discharge.

By the way, we are talking about a "cell", not a "battery": these are effects that affect each individual cell in the battery.
